# Мониторинг поля БД Postgresql

Tags: java, postgresql

ситуация вот какая: есть таблица в бд Postgresql,в ней есть поле "статус". Требуется выполнить некий кусок Java-кода, при любом изменении статуса. Подскажите, пожалуйста, какими средствами можно это сделать?

Comment: А статус будет меняться через Java-приложение или вручную?

Comment: Статус меняется из стороннего веб-приложения.

Comment: тогда сканировать статус с необходимым интервалом

Comment: Как вариант установить расширение pl/java (https://tada.github.io/pljava/) и написать на java триггер по изменению таблицы

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Можно создать триггер в базе:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION notify() RETURNS TRIGGER AS $$
    BEGIN
        SELECT pg_notify('status', TG_TABLE_NAME);
        RETURN NEW;
    END;
$$ LANGUAGE plpgsql;

CREATE TRIGGER table_change 
AFTER UPDATE OF STATUS ON table_name
FOR EACH ROW EXECUTE PROCEDURE notify();
```

А на стороне Java приложения слушать это событие при помощи ([pgjdbc-ng-0.6-complete.jar](http://impossibl.github.io/pgjdbc-ng/releases/pgjdbc-ng-0.6-complete.jar)):

```
import com.impossibl.postgres.api.jdbc.PGConnection;
import com.impossibl.postgres.api.jdbc.PGNotificationListener;
import com.impossibl.postgres.jdbc.PGDataSource;    
import java.sql.Statement;

public static void listenToMessage(){
    PGDataSource dataSource = new PGDataSource();
    dataSource.setHost("localhost");
    dataSource.setPort(5432);
    dataSource.setDatabase("database_name");
    dataSource.setUser("user");
    dataSource.setPassword("password");

    PGNotificationListener listener = (int processId, String channelName, String payload) 
        -> System.out.println(payload);

    try (PGConnection connection = (PGConnection) dataSource.getConnection();
        Statement statement = connection.createStatement()){
        statement.execute("LISTEN status");
        connection.addNotificationListener(listener);
        while (<условие закрытия соединения>){ }
    } catch (Exception e) {
        System.err.println(e);
    }
}
```

Comment: Подскажите, пожалуйста, как мне в данном случае обеспечить постоянный мониторинг статуса? при while(true) в условии закрытия возникают предупреждения, а затем эксепшены: PM com.impossibl.postgres.jdbc.ThreadedHousekeeper$HousekeeperReference cleanup
WARNING: Cleaning up leaked statement
Allocation occurred @ и exception: java.sql.SQLException: Connection Error: io.netty.util.concurrent.BlockingOperationException: DefaultChannelPromise@6cac3f20(incomplete)